# How to add another property to the element of array based on mapping

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, properties, mapping

In Powershell I have the following array

```
foreach ($Record in $Records)
{ write-host $Record
}

@{car=OPEL; count=3}
@{car=BMW; count=2}
@{car=OPEL; count=8}
@{car=AUDI; count=3}
@{car=FORD; count=5}
@{car=FORD; count=4}
@{car=OPEL; count=4}
@{car=AUDI; count=5}
@{car=BMW; count=3}
```

I want to add another property of each element in the array, which should be direct mapping from property "car"

```
car     manufacturer
OPEL    GM
BMW     Bayerishe Motoren Werke
AUDI    Volkswagen group
FORD    FORD Motor Company
```

and so on, the list with manufacturers has over 100 different values, and the inital array should become

```
@{car=OPEL; count=3; manufacturer=GM}
@{car=BMW; count=2; manufacturer=Bayerishe Motoren Werke}
@{car=OPEL; count=8; manufacturer=GM}
@{car=AUDI; count=3; manufacturer=Volkswagen group}
@{car=FORD; count=5; manufacturer=FORD Motor Company}
@{car=FORD; count=4; manufacturer=FORD Motor Company}
@{car=OPEL; count=4; manufacturer=GM}
@{car=AUDI; count=5; manufacturer=Volkswagen group}
@{car=BMW; count=3; manufacturer=Bayerishe Motoren Werke}
```

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?
What if the array is object with properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you obtained the `$Records` array using `Import-Csv` or something, as what you show is an array of **objects**.

The easiest thing to do here is to create a lookup Hashtable that servers as a mapping between the car brand and its manufacturer:

```
# create a mapping lookup Hashtable
$map = @{
    'OPEL' = 'GM'
    'BMW'  = 'Bayerishe Motoren Werke'
    'FORD' = 'FORD Motor Company'
    'AUDI' = 'Volkswagen Group'
}
# use the $map to add a new property to each of the records
foreach ($Record in $Records){ 
    $Record | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'manufacturer' -Value $map[$Record.car]
}
```

Now you can save this `$Records` array back to for instance a CSV file

```
$Records | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\CarsAndManufacturers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Display as table on screen or in a GridView

```
$Records | Format-Table -AutoSize  # or: $Records | Out-GridView
```

Or as you did before:

```
foreach ($Record in $Records) { 
    Write-Host $Record
}
```

Output as Table looks like this:

```
car  count manufacturer           
---  ----- ------------           
OPEL 3     GM                     
BMW  2     Bayerishe Motoren Werke
OPEL 8     GM                     
AUDI 3     Volkswagen Group       
FORD 5     FORD Motor Company     
FORD 4     FORD Motor Company     
OPEL 4     GM                     
AUDI 5     Volkswagen Group       
BMW  3     Bayerishe Motoren Werke
```

Comment: Actually the input is not from csv file, but JSON, which is result from a query, does this make any difference?

Comment: @GeorgiGochev Nope, no difference. That is the default stringyfied way PowerShell uses to display objects with `Write-Host`. How you got that array doesn't matter, either from JSON, CSV or XML